# Displaying incorrect values in PickerView in iphone application.

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

This is my code to display pickerview.

```
 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;
    CGSize limitSize = CGSizeMake(300.0f, 50.0f);
    CGSize textSize;
    CGRect labelRect;

    switch ([pickerView tag]) {

        case 1: //Quiz picker
        {    
            //m_txtPurpose.text=@"Test";
            QuizGenre *quiz = [m_arrQuizGenre objectAtIndex:row];
            NSString *title = [quiz m_quizGenreName];
            textSize = [title sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:limitSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            labelRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width, textSize.height);
            NSLog(@"length:%i title:%@",[title length],title);
            NSLog(@"h:%f w:%f",textSize.height,textSize.width);
            if (pickerLabel == nil)
            {
                pickerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect] autorelease];
                [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
                [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                [pickerLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
                [pickerLabel setText:title]; 
                [pickerLabel setNumberOfLines:3];


            }

            break;  
        case 2:  //Purpose picker
            {
                //cost.text = @"ABC";
                Purpose *prp = [m_arrPurpose objectAtIndex:row];
                NSString *title = [prp m_purposeName];
                textSize = [title sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:limitSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                labelRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width, textSize.height);
                NSLog(@"length:%i title:%@",[title length],title);
                NSLog(@"h:%f w:%f",textSize.height,textSize.width);
                if (pickerLabel == nil)
                {
                    pickerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect] autorelease];
                    [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
                    [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                    [pickerLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                    [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
                    [pickerLabel setText:title]; 
                    [pickerLabel setNumberOfLines:3];


                }
                break;
            default:

                break;
            }

        }
    }
    return pickerLabel;
}
```

My Picker view is Displaying wrong value after 6th row. 
I have 13 values in my Quiz picker view.
like Quiz genre: 1>Arts 2> Geography 3> General knowledge up to number 13> Television.
after 6th value it starts from first record. here is the image

[image: Wrong Value in picker snapshot]

insted it should display some thing like this. movies, music, television, politics and so forth.
Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: have you check  is title  coming different for each row?

Comment: Ya man I have checked it its coming different for each row.

Comment: uhm, there seems to be something wrong with your braces. Is that something you forgot when copy/paste your code ? Without seeing the rest I also think that you could rewrite much of your code, by leaving just the *title creation inside switch statement. All the rest could go outside.

Answer (score 0):

I Have found the right solution for this problem. What this code was doing is after six records it was refreshing the picker and this condition "if (pickerLabel == nil)" was becoming false Hence it was repeating the same records. I once I copied this lines of code in to else part as well its working fine for me.

```
 else{
                [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
                [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                [pickerLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
                [pickerLabel setText:title]; 
                [pickerLabel setNumberOfLines:3];
      }
```

may it can be helpful to others who facing same problem like me.